# Wamp/Apache/PHP config and the DEPRECATED error displayed only 1 time

Tags: apache-http-server, php, wamp

I have been recommended in stackoverflow to post my question here, it is realated to wamp64/php/apache.

The deprecated functions error message is displayed only after a restart of my server and on the first time I display the page.

After, I can refresh the page as many time I want, no way to get the message again.

I'd like to fix the deprecated functions so it's quite annoying that the message is not displayed permanently.

display_error is on, error_reporting is E_ALL.

I use wamp64, Apache 2.4-MySQL 5 & 8-MariaDB 10-PHP 5 & 7

The log shows that the error is raised also only 1 time, not a anymore after. So I'm suspecting a cache story but where...?

Same issue happens regardless the browser.

Any idea? Thanks a lot Nico.

Comment: Where is the error / warning displayed? If its in the log as "display_error is on, error_reporting is E_ALL." this is not an error - its advice as to the configuration if php.  If it is displaying in the page, what exactly is it throwing up?

Comment: in the HTML page, I see this: "( ! ) Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Paginator has a deprecated constructor in C:\wamp64\www\ParklandLite-Committee\libraries\PHP_Functions\pagination.php on line 3" but in the PHP.log, it is recorded like this: Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Paginator has a deprecated constructor in C:\wamp64\www\ParklandLite-Committee\libraries\PHP_Functions\pagination.php on line 3.

Comment: So, I'd like to understand why it is raised only the first time and not always. I need always to maintain the code upfront before it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find the answer. The issue is coming for the PHP cache.

To allow to display the "notice", I need to deactivate the caching system in PHP.

To do so:

- php.ini, set opcache.enable =0

Re-start the server, it works fine. Of course, it's for development purpose only, not production.

I hope this helps